# Procedimiento para borrar una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

hice un procedimiento almacenado para eliminar una tabla si existe qe se le pasa por parametro, este es mi código:

```
create procedure CrearTabla
@Tabla varchar (100)

as

if OBJECT_NAME(@tabla) is not null
   begin
      drop table @tabla
   end
go
```

Pero no me funciona. Me podrian dar una mano? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Que quiere decir que no funciona? que error devuelve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer esto, necesitas SQL dinámico (pero por favor, ten cuidado con "SQL injection"):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CrearTabla @Tabla varchar(100)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(300);

IF OBJECT_ID(@tabla, 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Tabla);
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

Comment: Hola Lamak, antesque nada mchas gracias, lo probe, pero me arroja un error. 
exec dbo.CrearTabla 'productos' y me da el error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'productos' to data type int. Me lo creo bien al procedimiento, pero no entiendo que va mal

Comment: Me parece que no estás usando el mismo código, la verdad

Comment: fue copy paste del tuyo... y se guardo bien, el problema es en la ejecucion... no se porque me arroja ese error.

Comment: @GALS actualicé mi respuesta, el error era por usar `OBJECT_NAME()`, que recibe un id de objeto (`int`) en vez de `OBJECT_ID()` que recibe el nombre de un objeto

Comment: Funciono genial!!!! Muchas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: Edité la respuesta para agregarle el parámetro `'U'` a la llamada a `object_id`, de otra manera, daría error si se le pasa, por decir algo, el nombre de un constraint o de una vista, pues encontraría que si existe un objeto, y luego intentaría borrar una tabla con ese nombre, cosa que no necesariamente existe.

Comment: @jachguate toda la razón, gracias

Answer (score -2):

detalles que noto es que falta un END para cerrar el procedure. Además de que deberías preguntar si existe esa tabla.

Voy a recrear el procedure como creo que debería funcionar.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CrearTabla
@Tabla varchar (100)

as

  IF(@Tabla IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @tabla
  END
END
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, esto funciona, pero debo corroborar si existe como objeto de la base de datos primero....

Comment: Si la variable es objeto de la base de datos, o si la tabla lo es?

Comment: No, el último `END` está sobrando, además de que ésto sólo se puede hacer con SQL dinámico

Comment: Es verdad, en mis procedures suelo poner AS BEGIN para cerrarlo con un END. Mis disculpas.